# Is fopen() forbidden in WP?

Tags: filesystem

I badly need to create an .XML file inside my theme every time user comes to my site.

But I can't.

This code in header:

```
    <?php $ourFileName = "testFile.txt";
          $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
          fclose($ourFileHandle); ?>
```

Just does nothing. It doesn't display "can't open file", but it doesn't create the file as well.

I'm testing it at my /localhost machine and this code works perfectly everywhere there (so file permissions are alright), but not in Wordpress.

Why is it happening? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File system access is tricky thing between different possible server configurations. If you need to implement it reliably in WP you should look into its API for such.

See [Using the WP_Filesystem](http://ottopress.com/2011/tutorial-using-the-wp_filesystem/).

Answer (score 2):

It's not a WordPress problem; WordPress will execute fopen() just like any other PHP function.

It may be an issue with your server configuration (e.g. safe mode).

Comment: To expand on Chip's answer, make sure that the directory you are writing to (which wasn't specified) has write permissions *for the server*. A quick test is to specify `/tmp/testfile.txt` for your file and see if that works -- it probably will.

Comment: that's strange, because I've got clean, valid XAMPP installation and fopen() works EVERYWHERE excepting Wordpress... So I'm not sure about server configuration issues...

Comment: I've seen fopen() used - to incredibly ill intent - in some of the Themes submitted to the WPORG Theme repository.